# How does Firebase compares a variable (== vs ===) in Data Rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, comparison, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

> **Information that is given below is straight from Firebase website.**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> When a client tries to access /users/barney, the $user default
>   location will match with $user being equal to "barney". So the .read
>   rule will check if auth.uid === 'barney'. As a result, reading
>   /users/barney will succeed only if the client is authenticated with a
>   uid of "barney".

Firebase is good at documenting, but I didn't find any deep discussion about using "==" or "===". As long as I know it works like how JavaScript does.

According to their documentation

> if auth.uid === 'barney'. As a result, reading
>   /users/barney will succeed only if the client is authenticated with a
>   uid of "barney".

Sometimes I've seen

```
"$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $user"
 }
```

**So my question is which one is the right way to do it? What is happening when we use "==" and "===" in rules?**

Comment: What about your question is different from [the one you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)? As far as I can tell, the answers there answer your question. Given that [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) it claims the expressions are "JavaScript-like," and so barring documentation to the contrary, the same meaning of `==` and `===` presumably applies?

Comment: I want to know if Firebase treats "==" and "===" same!

Comment: Well, it says the syntax is "JavaScript-like." Unless they tell you something else, doesn't that tell you what `==` and `===` do?

Comment: I thought it does like Javascript, but I haven't been able to find about that. Even if they do "auth.uid === 'barney'" it would contradict their document. Because if they use "===" that means they are checking if th auth.uid is also string and not comparing the content of "auth.uid"!

Comment: @user2884707bond "Used to check if two variables in a rules expression have the same type and value"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you consult the Firebase Database Security Rules API [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/), you will see the following definitions for [equals](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#equals):

> #### === (equals)
>
> ...
>   **Note:: == IS TREATED AS ===.** If you use == in your security rules, it will be translated to === when the rules are run.

and for [not equals](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#not_equals):

> #### !== (not equals)
>
> ...
>   **Note: != IS TREATED AS !==.** If you use != in your security rules, it will be translated to !== when the rules are run.

Comment: is the same for >= and <=

Answer (score 1):

I think Firebase treats all === as == (similarly all !== as !=).

My evidence is that the [Bolt Compiler](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) converts triple operators in your bolt file to double operators in the rules JSON output.